# Create a SPD 2010 Workflow To Check, Verify Date, and Delete an Empty Folder

Tags: 2010, workflow, document-library

I am trying to find out if there is a way to create a workflow (SPD 2010) for a Document Library that will delete an empty folder from the library if it has been empty for more than a specific number of days. Is that even remotely possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to do this with SPD 2010 workflows OOTB, it's certainly possible to build a workflow in Visual Studio and perform these actions.  It might be possible using [iLoveSharePoint's Codeplex tool](http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/), specifically the **Get Folder Action**.  I haven't tried this particular action, but I've used this tool before and it's fantastic. I would give this a shot first, then resort to making a custom workflow if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could work using SharePoint Designer.

You can create a workflow bound to the Folder content type. Your logic would look like this:

```
If (CurrentItem.Modified Date > X days)
Delete CurrentItem
```